# How to break out of a series of separate statements after an exception in C#

Tags: c#, click

I have a button click event that executes a group of file copy operations. Each copy operation is surrounded in it's own try/catch. I would like that in the event the user cancels or something goes wrong, it exits the rest of the file copy operations and returns the user back to the main program. Because each of the file copy statements are dependent on certain conditions, I can't just surround all of them with a single try/catch. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just put a `return` in the catch

e.g.

```
public void BigMethod()
{
    try
    { 
       // op1
    } catch
    {
      //some cleanup
      //some error message
      return // this will exit method here
    }

    try
    { 
       // op2
    } catch
    {
      //some cleanup
      //some error message
      return // this will exit method here
    }

}
```

Comment: OMG. I can't believe it. Once again I'm caught looking for the hard way to do something when return is all I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One approach:
Place all those try-catches in one big try-catch.
And if one of them fails, throw an exception so that it's caught by the outer try-catch, that way the rest of the try-catches don't execute.

Example:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        if(UserWantsTo())
            CopyFile();
        else
            throw new Exception("User doesn't want Copy1");
    }
    catch(Exception Copy1Ex)
    {
        throw Copy1Ex;
    }

    // repeat as many file-copies here.

}
catch (Exception OuterException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("One of the file copy operations failed: " + OuterException.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool problem = false;

try{}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//do your thing 
problem = true;
}

if(!problem){try/catch}
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow user to cancel:

You will need to create a Thread for this operation since the file copy is being handled on the main UI Thread. Once you set this up with threads, the UI will be able to listen for cancel events to which you can opt out of the file copy execution.

To skip if there's an error:

Just set `error` to `true` if an exception occurs:

```
// Process file 1
if(!ProcessFile()){

   // Processfile 2
   if(!ProcessFile()){

     //etc..
   }

}


private bool ProcessFile(){
    bool error = false;

    try{
       // do work   
    }
    catch{
       error = true;    
    }
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes. Do not surround each one with a try/catch. If you're sure you need all those catch blocks (logging) then re-throw the exception from the catch block.

```
try
{
    CopyAction();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   LogError(ex);

   throw; // not: throw ex;       
   // or maybe:
   throw new MoreSpecificException("message", ex); 
}
```

If in doubt, post some (simplified) code for further discussion.